# How to animate a line in different colors using D3 and leaflet?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I am a newbie to d3 and following example to animate a path using Leaflet and D3.js:[Tutorial Link](http://zevross.com/blog/2014/09/30/use-the-amazing-d3-library-to-animate-a-path-on-a-leaflet-map)

After following this link I wanted to change the color of the line after **time** is greater than 10.After then I realised the function I should Look is

```
     function tweenDash() {
            return function(t) {
                //total length of path (single value)
                var l = linePath.node().getTotalLength(); 


                interpolate = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);
                //t is fraction of time 0-1 since transition began
                var marker = d3.select("#marker");

                // p is the point on the line (coordinates) at a given length
                // along the line. In this case if l=50 and we're midway through
                // the time then this would 25.
                var p = linePath.node().getPointAtLength(t * l);
                //Move the marker to that point
                marker.attr("transform", "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")"); //move marker
                console.log(interpolate(t))
                return interpolate(t);
            }
        } //end tweenDash
```

So if I can access the time element inside the tweenDash function then I can be able to change the color .But the t is the interpolation points and not equal to the time counter.I am not sure is there any way to change the color of the line after t is greater than 10 .Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`t` is a normalized value `[0..1]` of the interval the animation runs. Often used in an easing function to transform `t`.

if the animation duration is 2000ms then `t=0.5` is at 1000ms from the animation start.

So do the calculation to determine for what `t` value you have `10`.

`10` what?

A lot of the stuff in your `tweenDash` is constant in regard to `t` so it can be put before the `return function` or you can only recalculate it when the zoom reset function has been called due to a zoom or translate of the map.

Comment: 10 is the time element in the point.gejson (JSON attribute).So i cannot convert the t into the time element and that is the problem i am facing since I cannot access the time element inside the tweendash function

Comment: @IS5006_10Group: split your points list from the GeoJSON in 2 groups, at `10`, calculate the length of each piece you need, use this length in your total line animation instead of a `t` value